# Web audio player for M4a

Tags: html

i am playing mp3 file in my web with google player :

```
http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf
```

and i can't playing m4a files with this player too.

there is any way to play m4a files with this player too? or there is another player to play m4a files in my browser?

this is how i am using the player:

```
<embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" flashvars=\"audioUrl=songUrl&autoPlay=true\" src=\"http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf\" width=\"400\" height=\"27\" quality=\"best\"></embed>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats), this is a bit of a complex issue: Flash (the technology your audio player, and most others on the web currently, is based on) is able to play MPEG-4 content, but only when declaring the content *video*, not audio. Why this is, I have no idea.

You may be able to play M4A sound files if you can find a Flash *video* player that suits your needs. Alternatively, consider using HTML 5 Audio.

> **Update:** [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), a jQuery/Flash/HTML5-Based audio player, claims to be able to play MPEG-4 Audio content. You should be able to use that.