# how to play wav stream in safari vai javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, wav

I've tried Audio / embed / Object, but fail at all of them.

play wave file is ok, but cannot play stream.

`<audio><source src="sample.wav" /></audio>` **OK**

`<audio><source src="http://mydomain/stream" /></audio>` **fail**

`<object data="sample.wav"></object>` **OK**

`<object data="http://mydomain/stream"></object>` **fail**

jPlayer also cannot work!

I found a clue:
If when I play it in firefox before, then safari works. It seems firefox download it so the safari can play it in quicktime's cache.
code:
`<embed src="http://10.224.91.28:8080/cas/auth.do?cmd=getaudiobycaptchaid&id=Q71UNBGRFOI00A8NDNBV76BTNE&clientid=9e1f73ca9d0ff1e07ca87f7660d1b911" height="45" width="170" type="audio/x-wav"/>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all check this [Supported Video and Audio Formats](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats) for audio/ video support information.

[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), a `jQuery/Flash/HTML5-Based audio player`, claims to be able to play MPEG-4 Audio content. You should be able to use that.

[jPlayer - Server Response - MIME Type](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response)

Another player is [JW flash player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), that you can try. check [supported types](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats)

Reference:
[Web audio player for M4a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055639/web-audio-player-for-m4a)
[Seeking through a streamed MP3 file with HTML5 <audio> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798931/seeking-through-a-streamed-mp3-file-with-html5-audio-tag)
[How to play binary MP3 stream with jQuery/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173861/how-to-play-binary-mp3-stream-with-jquery-javascript)

check this if it found somewhat relevant to your problem:
[iPhone: Phonegap: Audio Playing in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959275/iphone-phonegap-audio-playing-in-background)

Comment: check [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats) and [another](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12535/video-delivery-rtmp-streaming)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [html5audioplayer](http://www.scottandrew.com/pub/html5audioplayer/). It slags a bit, but works in the end....